# Highmaps caribbean map

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to display points(lat/long) with highmaps. I have successfully done that for US because there is a finished map for that.
Now I am trying to display points in the caribbean. I found the following link to create a map for the caribbean: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/plotoptions/series-allareas-false/)

The problem is with this option I can only set values for the whole country. But I need to set specific points in the different countries with values. Example is California Map.[image]

I tried to update the sample code to:

```
import mapDataUSWithoutCentral from "@highcharts/map-collection/custom/north-america-no-central.geo.json"

    var dataCaribbean = [{
    'hc-key': 'cu', //Cuba
    value: 0
},{
    'hc-key': 'bs', //Bahamas
    value: 0
},{
  'hc-key': 'tc', //Turks and Caicos Islands
  value: 0
},{
  'hc-key': 'ky', //Cayman Islands
  value: 0
},{
  'hc-key': 'ht', //Haiti
  value: 0
},{
  'hc-key': 'do', //Dominican Republic
  value: 0
},{
  'hc-key': 'jm', //Jamaica
  value: 0
},{
  'hc-key': 'pr', //Puerto Rico
  value: 0
},
{ z: 10, keyword: "demo", lat: 23.113592, lon: -82.366592, color: '#ff0000' }
];

  const mapOptionsCaribbean = {
    chart: {
      map: mapDataUSWithoutCentral
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Caribbean'
    },
    mapNavigation: {
      enabled: true,
  },
    series: [{
      data: dataCaribbean,
      mapData: mapDataUSWithoutCentral,
      joinBy: 'hc-key',
      allAreas: false,
      name: 'Random data',
      states: {
          hover: {
              color: '#a4edba'
          }
      },
      dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '{point.name}'
      }
  }]
  }
```

But the result is only this:
[image]
The last point in the data array is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another series with `mapbubble` type and add `proj4` library:

```
series: [...,
  {
    type: "mapbubble",
    data: [...]
  }
]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-o5roi

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mapbubble.data

Comment: Amazing, Thank you really much